# Teradata view has space in field name that I cannot change...how do I write select statement with where clause

Tags: sql, teradata

VIEW Definition

```
DBName.ViewName AS LOCKING ROW FOR ACCESS 
SEL
MATL_ID                        ,
CD "Company Code"
FROM DBName.TableName;
```

Please note I cannot change the view - I can only query...

the following works...

```
select matl_id, "Company Code"
from DBName.ViewName;
```

but this does not

```
select matl_id, "Company Code"
from DBName.ViewName
where "Company Code" in ("Abc", "Xyz");
```

Any help with last statement appreciated

Answer (score 5):

replace `in ("Abc", "Xyz")` with `in ('Abc', 'Xyz')`

`"` is used for objects' qualification.
`'` is used for strings